# How to obtain the text color of a single item within an Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, getview

My ListView contains items that are different text colors. I need to grab the color state of each item to to be saved within the onSaveInstanceState of my fragment.

```
    ListView lvItems = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    lvItemsArray.add("Testing1234");

    lvItemsAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), lvItemsArray);
    lvItems.setAdapter(lvItemsAdapter);
```

Comment: try this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCurrentTextColor())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it from another user on here, thanks.

```
    View view = ListAdapter.getView(0, null, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myitemRow);
    ColorStateList mlist = textView.getTextColors();
    int color = mlist.getDefaultColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

LitView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
                   Log.d("TextView",""+arg1.TextView.getTextcolor());
    });
```

Comment: Obviously you are adding some text get like thisa

Comment: To confirm I'm not clicking the list view. I need something to parse through it to check the text color of each item. So I wouldn't be using onItemClick